# response and request headers in jwt

Tags: php, angularjs, json, authentication, jwt

I'm currently using `jwt` (json web tokens) for authentication system in my `AngularJS` app. There are some different aspects in the implementations. I have two questions:

**First:** Why do we use request header for sending tokens? Why we don't send them like an ordinary XHR? Something like this:

```
$http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = myToken;
```

**Second:** Why do we response as `401 Unauthorized`  header in our server and handle with an interceptor? Why not just a json returned with a flag? Something like this in php:

```
header("HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized");
```